# nodejs delete last element from sorted json for each key if there multiple record exists

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, lodash

I have a sorted json by descending order(pid,type,year) given below

```
[{
    "pId" : "60B15",
    "info" : {      
        "type" : "NT",
        "year" : 2018
    }
},
{
    "pId" : "60B15",
    "info" : {      
        "type" : "NT",
        "year" : 2017
    }
},
{
    "pId" : "60B15",
    "info" : {      
        "type" : "MT",
        "year" : 2017
    }
},
{
    "pId" : "59B15",
    "info" : {      
        "type" : "NT",
        "year" : 2018
    }
},
{
    "pId" : "59B15",
    "info" : {      
        "type" : "MT",
        "year" : 2018
    }
},
{
    "pId" : "59B15",
    "info" : {      
        "type" : "MT",
        "year" : 2017
    }
}]
```

Now I want to delete last record for each different pId if there is multiple type exists, if there is single type for example for pId 60B15 there is single type MT and I dont want to delete it. Need output below

```
[{
    "pId" : "60B15",
    "info" : {      
        "type" : "NT",
        "year" : 2018
    }
},
{
    "pId" : "60B15",
    "info" : {      
        "type" : "MT",
        "year" : 2017
    }
},
{
    "pId" : "59B15",
    "info" : {      
        "type" : "NT",
        "year" : 2018
    }
},
{
    "pId" : "59B15",
    "info" : {      
        "type" : "MT",
        "year" : 2018
    }
}]
```

If it can be done by nodejs lodash then it will be great and I want it dynamically there is not only two types MT and NT, there are lot of types exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correct: You will only have the latest entry (highest year) for every combination of pId and type.

For a sorted array, ECMAScript 6:

```
var input = [{
    "pId" : "60B15",
    "info" : {
        "type" : "NT",
        "year" : 2018
    }
},
{
    "pId" : "60B15",
    "info" : {
        "type" : "NT",
        "year" : 2017
    }
},
{
    "pId" : "60B15",
    "info" : {
        "type" : "MT",
        "year" : 2017
    }
},
{
    "pId" : "59B15",
    "info" : {
        "type" : "NT",
        "year" : 2018
    }
},
{
    "pId" : "59B15",
    "info" : {
        "type" : "MT",
        "year" : 2018
    }
},
{
    "pId" : "59B15",
    "info" : {
        "type" : "MT",
        "year" : 2017
    }
}];

const result = input.filter((element, index, array) => index == 0 || !(element.pId === array[index-1].pId &&
      element.info.type === array[index-1].info.type));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: what about if I want to delete lowest year for every combination

Comment: @JohneDoe I don't understand. My solution keeps the highest year, so it deletes the lowest year (and other lower years). Do you want to delete **only** the lowest year, or do you want to **keep** only the lowest year of every combination?

Comment: Delete highest year

Comment: @JohneDoe One possibility would be to sort the json in ascending order. So the script will behave in exact opposite way. Otherwise this piece of code should also achieve what you want: `const result = input.filter((element, index, array) => index == (array.length - 1) || !(element.pId === array[index+1].pId && element.info.type === array[index+1].info.type));` (not tested) **PS:** If it doesn't work, it could help if you provide the result you want to get.

Answer (score 1):

This function will do the same you are asking, It will give you unique pID and type combination, regardless of number of types you have.

For each new item, it checks if the type,id combination exists in the previous items or not. if it exists the flag turns false and item is not added to new array.

```
function makeUnique(arr){
    var newArr = [];
    for(let item of arr){
       let flag = true; 
       for(let newItem of newArr){
         if(newItem.pId == item.pId && newItem.info.type == item.info.type){
            flag = false;
            break;
         }
       }
       if(flag){
        newArr.push(item);
       }
    }
    return newArr
}
```

Comment: what about if I want to delete lowest year for every combination